# How to install dependencies of created libraries into parent app in angular library creation

Tags: angular, dependencies, angular-library

I am creating a angular library using ng-packager and doing a npm_pack to create it into a tgz format

I have installed few dependencies in the libraries (like moment, angular material etc)

Now in my parent application I installed this library.

When I run the application it throws error as momemt/angular materials not found.

Only if I install those dependencies again into my parent application the library is working.

I tried adding the dependencies of moment/angular materials into dependencies/dev dependencies of the library but still the result was same.

I am not sure what I am missing here. 
Can someone help on how to install them without me manually installing all missing ones.

I tried in peer dependencies but that lead to some other error

Versions:

```
Angular CLI: 8.1.1
Node: 10.15.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.1.1
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.801.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.801.1
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.801.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.801.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.801.1
@angular-devkit/core               8.1.1
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.1.1
@angular/cdk                       8.1.2
@angular/material                  8.1.4
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   8.1.1
@schematics/angular                8.1.1
@schematics/update                 0.801.1
ng-packagr                         5.3.0
rxjs                               6.5.2
typescript                         3.4.5
webpack                            4.35.2
```

### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "lib1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build_lib": "ng build lib1",
    "npm_pack": "cd dist/lib1 && npm pack",
    "package": "npm run build_lib && npm run npm_pack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.801.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.1",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^5.1.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tsickle": "^0.35.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code that you tried out, also put the angular details by simply pasting the data from `ng version` in terminal/command prompt.

Comment: updated the versions. Code I am not sure what to add.

Comment: you can check `peerDependency` over here https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/dependency-types/ , it will help you I believe.

Comment: My actual requirement is like I want to create a package like how we install other packages to our angular application.
Eg: Creating a package like moment generally doesnt ask us to install what moment needs internally. All its dependent package will be available by default for us internally.

But in my case it is explicitly asking to install all dependent packages that i used to create my custom package which is what I want a solution on how to rectify it.

Comment: You need to create your project as a library and not as  an application then you can achieve your requirement... Let me gather some info and I will give you an answer...

Comment: yes pls some sample will be really helpful

Comment: I followed this link https://nezhar.com/blog/up-and-running-library-development-with-angular-7/ and created sample library.

I also referred how other open source packages are created which we are using.
Like bootstrap etc.. In their package.json I am not seeing peerDependencies at al. 
All I see is only the devDep and dependencies. But still when i install them it doesnt expect anything to install apart from it.
Not sure what I am missing here :(

Comment: Please add your application package.json

Comment: I have updated my question with package.json. Here consider I want to use moment in my library. If I add it and then use this lib1 in another application as package that application while running throws me moment not found error and if I install moment in that application then it is working fine which is not the expected way